# Kubernetes reports different apiVersion for the same Deployment

Tags: kubernetes

Due to Kubernetes removing deprecated API I am trying to figure out an apiVersion of resources in a cluster and came across the following behavior.

When requesting definition for specific deployment, it reports an old api version:

```
> kubectl get deployment/some-deployment -o yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
...
```

Bud when requesting it for all resources api version reported as new for the same resource:

```
> kubectl get all -o yaml
...
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
...
```

Same goes when checking `selfLink` in metadata:

```
kubectl get all -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,API-version:.metadata.selfLink
and
kubectl get deployment/some-deployment -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,API-version:.metadata.selfLink
```

How should this be interpreted?

Kubernetes version is 1.15.7.

Answer (score 4):

Quoted from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58131#issuecomment-356823588)

> `kubectl get deployment foo` is ambiguous, since the server has deployments in multiple api groups. When a resource exists in multiple api groups, kubectl uses the first group listed in discovery docs published by the server which contains the resource. For backwards compatibility, that is the **extensions** api group.
>
> If you want to ensure you get a deployment in the apps api group, fully qualify the resource you are requesting by running `kubectl get deployments.apps test-nginx`
>
> If you want a specific version, like v1, in the apps api group, include that as well: `kubectl get deployments.v1.apps test-nginx`

Also from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58131#issuecomment-404466779)

> What stored version is used for?
>
> It is the serialized version in etcd. Whenever you fetch an object, the api server reads it from etcd, converts it into an internal version, then converts it to the version you requested.

So, If you run

```
$ kubectl get deployments nginx -o name
deployment.extensions/nginx
```

As you can see  requested version for above command is `deployment.extensions`

And If you run

```
$ kubectl get all -o name
...
deployment.apps/nginx
```

The requested version is `deployment.apps`. so, it returns the version with `apps/v1`

Ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58131

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't really explain an apiVersion that is showed when running `kubectl get all`

Comment: It makes it little bit more clear. So when I request info for `deployment` Kubernetes gets minimal supported version in the cluster for that and retrieves info using it. But for retrieving `all` - minimal supported version is `apps/v1`? Would then `all` output be missing resources that do not support `apps/v1`?

Comment: It seems like api serving `kubectl get all` request has older version of api: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#customresourcedefinitionnames-v1beta1-apiextensions-k8s-io . Why isn't it used instead?